# Reference for the converse of Cartan's Theorem B

Tags: several-complex-variables, cohomology, reference-request

Cartan's theorem B states that every coherent analytic sheaf on a Stein manifold is acyclic.  Hartshorne claims that the converse to this theorem also holds, but doesn't supply a reference.  Does anyone where to find a proof of this fact?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually a more general result is true:
If $X$ is a complex *space* (maybe not smooth) and if $H^1(X,\mathcal I)$ is zero for all coherent sheaves of ideals $\mathcal I\subset \mathcal O_X$, then $X$ is a Stein space.
This is Proposition 52.6 In L.Kaup-B.Kaup's [*Holomorphic Functions of Several Variables*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Holomorphic_functions_of_several_variabl.html?id=nDgBsOurnAIC&redir_esc=y).
It is also proved in [Taylor's book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=i8lUNpZ379MC&source=gbs_similarbooks_r&redir_esc=y): Proposition 11.4.5

An amusing variant is that an open subset $U\subset \mathbb C^n$ is Stein iff  $H^i(U,\mathcal O)$ for all $1\leq i\leq n-1$. 
This is proved as Theorem 2, §5, Chapter V, page 159 of Grauert-Remmert's *Theory of Stein Spaces*.

Comment: For the second statement, I guess you mean $H^i(U, \mathcal O)=0$, right?

Comment: Dear @Henri: yes, it was a typo that I just corrected. Thanks a lot for alerting me to it.